# trying to work out where the submit request on stock x is going

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, web-scraping

I am currently working on a script which searches sneaker names on www.stockx.com. I have inspected the webpage to see the backend around the search box, just to see where the request is going and in which format. Since i don't know much js i was wondering if someone could explain to me what the below lines of code are doing.

Event: Invalid

```
function() {
  n && o.isFunction(n) && n.apply(this, arguments);
  try {
    return e.apply(this, arguments)
  } catch (n) {
    var t = n;
    throw t && window._rollbarWrappedError !== t && (o.isType(t, "string") 
   && (t = new String(t)), t._rollbarContext = r() || {}, 
   t._rollbarContext._wrappedSource = e.toString(), 
    window._rollbarWrappedError = t), t
   }
 }
```

Event: onChange

```
function(e) {
  var t = this.props.setSearchValue,
    a = e.target.value;
  t(a), this.setState({
    page: 0,
    productCategory: ""
  }), a.length > 0 ? this._executeSearch(a) : 
  (this._executeSearch.cancel(),this.reset())
}
```

Event OnClick

```
function(e) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    var t = e.target,
      a = 0;
    if (e.target.offsetParent)
      do {
        a += t.offsetTop, t = t.offsetParent
      } while (t);
    navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) && !window.MSStream ? window.scrollTo(0, a) : window.scrollTo(0, a - 46)
  }
```

Event: onKeyDown

```
function(t) {
  var a = this.props.urlPrefix;
  if (40 === t.keyCode && (this.setState({
    searchBoxId: t.target.id
  }), e(".list-item").first().focus(), t.preventDefault()), 13 === t.keyCode) {
    var o = this.props,
      n = o.verticalsWithResults,
      r = o.onlyOneVerticalWithResults;
    if (!o.value) return;
    if (r) {
      var i = n[0];
      h.browserHistory.push("".concat(a, "search/").concat(i, "?s=").concat(encodeURIComponent(this.props.value))), this.props.submitSearch(this.props.value), this.reset()
    } else h.browserHistory.push("".concat(a, "search?s=").concat(encodeURIComponent(this.props.value))), this.props.submitSearch(this.props.value), this.reset()
  }
}
```

My goal is to be able to find what happens when the submit button is clicked. Is there a URL i can send a POST request to with whatever gets typed in the search box.

Comment: browser developer tools console/network tabs take the guesswork out of this

Answer (score 1):

> *Primary question:* Is there a URL I can send a POST request to with whatever gets typed
>   in the search box.

https://stockx.com/api/browse?&_search=**SEARCH_TERM**&dataType=product

Example:

https://stockx.com/api/browse?&_search=**Jordan**&dataType=product

Result is a JSON array of Products with related details.  You can test this out yourself by placing the above URL in your browser to see the response.  From there, you can parse the response and get whatever data you want.

Spaces will need to be encoded.  Here is an example of a search for "Jordan 4":

https://stockx.com/api/browse?&_search=**Jordan%204**&dataType=product